# AlertDialog is not rendering correctly

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

As you can see in the screenshot, my alert dialog border is not rendering correctly.  It is placing a black background behind the dialog.  This only happens when I resize the dialog.  I'm new to android/monodroid so I don't really even know where to start looking for a cure.  You can see that the toast message renders the border properly (with a semi-transparent border).

Any thoughts on how I can get rid of the black background behind the dialog border ?

[image: screenshot]

resizing code:

```
Dialog dialog = db.Create();
WindowManagerLayoutParams p = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();
p.CopyFrom(dialog.Window.Attributes);
p.Width = 900;
p.Height = WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent;
dialog.Show();
dialog.Window.Attributes = p;
```

Comment: Maybe because you set the layout attributes after you show it

Comment: If I set the attributes before calling `.Show()` then the dialog does not resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice to use the DialogFragment instead of the older dialog, at work we have had quite a few problems with the older dialogs.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html
And this problem in specific on a few devices.